# tabular not showing with tex4ebook

Tags: tex4ebook

I have this LaTex code:

```
\documentclass{book}
    \begin{document}
    
Hello
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
\end{tabular}
Goodbye

\end{document}
```

It produces this when I run tex4ebook (works fine with pdflatex, but I'm making an ebook):

[image: epub with just hello and goodbye]

Why can't I see a table?

I have searched the tex4ebook issues for tabular and found nothing similar.  [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690494/xltabular-with-tex4ebook) looks similar but turns out to be about a slightly different package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a problem with the ebook viewer I was using.

```
Sudo apt install mupdf
```

installs the (1.19.0+ds1-2) version of mupdf, which doesn't show the tables but building version 1.23 from source does. (The tables also show up fine in calibre's ebook viewer and Amazon's kindle previewer)